# Storing word per word in an array from a single line in a text file

Tags: java

i have been working on a project that would scan a textfile line per line and at each line, each word in the line will be stored in an array

here is my code as of now. when it comes to the storing from the Answer.txt file, an error occurs. can someone please help me?

```
try
    {
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        //System.out.println(s);
        String[] Question = s.split(" ");

        for(int i=0;i<=Question.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Question[i]);
        }//debug

        s = sc2.nextLine();
        //System.out.println(s2);
        String[] Answer = s.split(" ");

        for(int c=0;c<=Answer.length;c++)
        {
            System.out.println(Answer[c]);
        }//debug
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        System.out.println("...");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the index counting all together with an "foreach" loop.

```
for (String s: Question){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're probably getting [ArrayIndexOutOfBounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) exception.

```
for(int i=0;i<=Question.length;i++)
```

Should be:

```
for(int i=0;i<Question.length;i++)
             ^
```

(The same for the other loop).

**Why**?

Remember that arrays are *zero-based* in Java. So if you have an array of size `N`, the indexes will be from `0` to `N - 1` (total sum of `N`).

Comment: +1..You were too fast.

Comment: oh my carelessness. Thank you Maroun!